# How to query mongodb by arrays of id

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a database field with the below structure:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5abcf1e8734d1d68b1b1cf46"
    },
    "name": "Sample 2",
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5abcf20b734d1d68b1b1cf60"
    },
    "name": "Sample 2",
},
```

I want to query the `_id` with an array to return all the data with the id inside the array.

```
db.user.find({_id: 
   {
 $in: 
    ["5abcf1e8734d1d68b1b1cf46", 
    "5abcf20b734d1d68b1b1cf60"]
}
})
```

Comment: You convert your string to `ObjectId`, since that's what those values really are. `db.user.find({ _id: { $in: ["5abcf1e8734d1d68b1b1cf46",    "5abcf20b734d1d68b1b1cf60"].map(o => new ObjectId(o)) } })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by doing:

```
db.user.find({_id: 
  {
 $in: 
[
 {"$oid": "5abcf1e8734d1d68b1b1cf46"}, 
 {"$oid": "5abcf20b734d1d68b1b1cf60"}]
 }
})
```

since the collection has "$oid" you need to pass an an array of objects with the keys as `$oid`